# Project specific preference page in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I want to enable project-based Preference-dialogs for our product. I stumble upon 2 different problems:

How do I store those project related informations. As an educated guess I would try this one:

- `IPreferenceStore store = new ScopedPreferenceStore(new ProjectScope(project.getIProject()), Activator.PLUGIN_ID)`;
- Afterwards set the "project store" as I want (for example inside a preference page as store)

How do I enable a Preference Page only for a project? I know I can call a preference dialog with some preselected pages using the `PreferenceUtils.createPreferenceDialogOn(…)`. Unfortunately the IDs of the preference pages have to defined in the `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages`extension point. But if they are inside this extension point, these pages are also in the global "Preferences" of the product. If they are not specified inside the EP the pages are not shown.

Any hints on that? Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:** What I actually wanted was a properties dialog, not a preference dialog. If you are working with property pages, the PreferenceUtils does not work at all. If you contribute a properties page via `org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages` it works well for the standard eclipse navigator - but how do I handle this inside a custom navigator (Common Navigator Framework)?

Comment: Maybe I should add, that I use FieldEditorPreferencePage as parent.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how you want this to appear to the user. When the user goes to Window -> Preferences, that's going to be global. Are you talking about having your preference page be accessible through the Properties associated with the project (in the Project Explorer for example, selecting the Project and then Properties)? This is certainly possible if that's what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to subclass `PropertiesPage` and then put a reference to it in your plugin.xml like this for example. This uses two different properties pages, one that is shown when a project is select, the other for a file. And they are both only present in the projects with the specified project nature.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
    <page
        class="com.oaklandsw.transform.editor.TransformProjectPropertiesPage"
    id="com.oaklandsw.transform.filePropPage"
    name="%appHandle">
    <enabledWhen>
    <and>
            <instanceof
             value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
        </instanceof>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource" >
                <test
                 property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                value="com.oaklandsw.transform.runtime.nature">
                </test>
            </adapt>   
    </and>
    </enabledWhen>
    </page> 
    <page class="com.oaklandsw.transform.editor.TransformFilePropertiesPage"
        id="com.oaklandsw.transform.projectPropPage" name="%appHandle">
        <enabledWhen>
            <and>
        <instanceof
            value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
        </instanceof>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource" >
                <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                    value="com.oaklandsw.transform.runtime.nature" />
            </adapt>        
            </and>
        </enabledWhen>
    </page>
</extension>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do stuff like this with a FieldEditorPreferencePage?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mutatis-mutandis/overlay-pages.html

Comment: This works in principal - I was able to contribute a properties page to the properties dialog. bMy problem here: We don't use the "standard" navigator; we wrote one ourselves using the common navigator framework. Here you don't have the possibily to open a properties dialog - and the above mentioned PreferenceUtils does not work, because... Well it's for preferences, not for properties ;)

Comment: I solved this problem: I have to provide a command with the id `org.eclipse.ui.file.properties` to my desired menu to get the properties dialog (and I thing the name of the command is somewhat misleading…)